# Node.js: Wrong extra bytes were wrote on Back pressure in writable stream

Tags: node.js, socket.io, backpressure

I made simple binary transmission with Socket.io to transfer file to server from client. I thought it worked, but I realized that size of the file was different. On writableStream.write failed, I attached drain event handler to keep wait until it can be rewrite and continue the writes, but each time drain event occurs, size of the file is increased by times of drain event fired, each 10240 bytes size that I set for each chunk transmission.

Before I'm writing the code here, I need to explain the code flow:

1. Client request uploading file
2. Server create empty file(create writable stream) and grant transmission
3. Client transfer data(chunk) until it ends
4. Server write the chunk with writable stream
5. Client ends transmission on sent all
6. Server close the writable stream.
7. Done!

This is server side code:

```
var writeStream = null;
var fileSize = 0;
var wrote = 0;

socket.on('clientRequestFileTransfer', (fileInfo) => {
    console.log(`Client request file transfer: ${fileInfo.name}(${fileInfo.size})`);

    fileSize = fileInfo.size;
    wrote = 0;

    writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/' + fileInfo.name);
    writeStream.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Write stream ended.');
    });

    console.log('File created.');
    socket.emit('serverGrantFileTransfer');
});

socket.on('clientSentChunk', (chunk) => {
    function write() {
        let writeDone = writeStream.write(chunk);

        if(!writeDone) {
            console.log('Back pressure!');
            return writeStream.once('drain', write);
        }
        else {
            wrote += chunk.length;
            console.log(`Wrote chunks: ${chunk.length} / ${wrote} / ${fileSize}`);
            socket.emit('serverRequestContinue');
        }
    }

    write();        
});
socket.on('clientFinishTransmission', () => {
    writeStream.end();
    console.log('Transmission complete!');
});
```

And it's client(added code for reading binary file):

```
var fileEl = document.getElementById('file');
fileEl.onchange = function() {
    var file = fileEl.files[0];
    if(!file) return;

    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = function() {
            var bin = fileReader.result;
            var chunkSize = 10240;
            var sent = 0;

            // make server knows the name and size of the file
            socket.once('serverGrantFileTransfer', () => {
                function beginTransfer() {
                    if(sent >= bin.byteLength) {
                        console.log('Transmission complete!');
                        socket.emit('clientFinishTransmission');
                        return;
                    }

                    var chunk = bin.slice(sent, sent + chunkSize);

                    socket.once('serverRequestContinue', beginTransfer);
                    socket.emit('clientSentChunk', chunk);

                    sent += chunk.byteLength;
                    console.log('Sent: ' + sent);
                }

                beginTransfer();
            });
            socket.emit('clientRequestFileTransfer', {
                name: file.name,
                size: file.size
            });

        };

        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
};
```

I tested this code with 4,162,611 bytes sized file and it had 1 write fails(1 back pressure). After uploads, I checked the size of created file, and it was 4,172,851 bytes which is 10240 bytes bigger than original one, and it is size of chunk(10240).

Sometimes write fails 2 times, than size is 20480 bytes bigger than original one which double size of the chunk that I sent.

I double checked my Backpressure code, but it seems nothing wrong to me. I'm using Node v6.2.2 and using Socket.io v1.6.0, tested from Chrome browser. Is there a something that I missed? Or did I misunderstood of backpresssure?
Any advice will be very appreciated.

### **UPDATE**

Looks like when back pressure happens, it wrote same data twice(as I said in comment). So I modified the code like this:

```
socket.on('clientSentChunk', (chunk) => {
    function write() {
        var writeDone = writeStream.write(chunk);
        wrote += chunk.length;

        if(!writeDone) {
            console.log('**************** Back pressure ****************');
            // writeStream.once('drain', write);
            // no rewrite, just continue transmission
            writeStream.once('drain', () => socket.emit('serverRequestContinue'));
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Wrote chunks: ${chunk.length} / ${wrote} / ${fileSize}`);
            socket.emit('serverRequestContinue');
        }
    }

    write();        
});
```

It worked. I'm quite confusing because when writable stream fails to write, it won't wrote the data into the stream, but actually not. Does anybody knows about this?

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like when back pressure occurs, it writes same data twice. As I know, when writable stream fails to write, it won't wrote data into the stream. Am I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is how you make the bin object in `var bin = ...;`. Could you please so the code here?

**Update**

---

Here is the backend code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(80);
var io = require('socket.io');
var fs = require('fs');

io = io.listen(server);


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //res.send({a:1})
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/socket_test_index.html');
});




io.on('connection', function(client) {  
    console.log('Client connected...', client);

    client.on('join', function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
    });

    setInterval(()=>{
        client.emit('news', 'news from server');
    }, 10000)


});

io.of('/upload', function(client){
    console.log('upload')
    logic(client);
})



function logic(socket) {



    var writeStream = null;
    var fileSize = 0;
    var wrote = 0;

    socket.on('clientRequestFileTransfer', (fileInfo) => {
        console.log(`Client request file transfer: ${fileInfo.name}(${fileInfo.size})`);

        fileSize = fileInfo.size;
        wrote = 0;

        writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/' + fileInfo.name);
        writeStream.on('close', () => {
            console.log('Write stream ended.');
        });

        console.log('File created.');
        socket.emit('serverGrantFileTransfer');
    });

    socket.on('clientSentChunk', (chunk) => {
        function write() {
            var writeDone = writeStream.write(chunk);

            if(!writeDone) {
                console.log('Back pressure!');
                return writeStream.once('drain', write);
            }
            else {
                wrote += chunk.length;
                console.log(`Wrote chunks: ${chunk.length} / ${wrote} / ${fileSize}`);
                socket.emit('serverRequestContinue');
            }
        }

        write();        
    });
    socket.on('clientFinishTransmission', () => {
        writeStream.end();
        console.log('Transmission complete!');
    });


    socket.emit('serverGrantFileTransfer', {});

}
```

Here is the html code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});


socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
});
</script>




<input type="file" id="file" />

<script>
var fileEl = document.getElementById('file');
fileEl.onchange = function() {
    var file = fileEl.files[0];
    if(!file) return;

    var socket = io('http://localhost/upload');

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = function() {
            var bin = fileReader.result;
            var chunkSize = 10240;
            var sent = 0;

            // make server knows the name and size of the file
            socket.once('serverGrantFileTransfer', () => {
                function beginTransfer() {
                    if(sent >= bin.byteLength) {
                        console.log('Transmission complete!');
                        socket.emit('clientFinishTransmission');
                        return;
                    }

                    var chunk = bin.slice(sent, sent + chunkSize);

                    socket.once('serverRequestContinue', beginTransfer);
                    socket.emit('clientSentChunk', chunk);

                    sent += chunk.byteLength;
                    console.log('Sent: ' + sent);
                }

                beginTransfer();
            });
            socket.emit('clientRequestFileTransfer', {
                name: file.name,
                size: file.size
            });

        };

        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
};

</script>
```

Copy them to the root dir in express project. I tested with two pictures and one .pdf file. All of them are transferred exactly the same bytes

Comment: Sure, I just added.

Comment: It's strange your code works very well on my laptop(Windows7, Node V4). I will paste my test above. Please check.

Comment: Does files you tested are big enough to occurs back pressure? It seems nothing different from my code.

Comment: What kind of the file you were transferring? I even tested with a .wmv video file (26,246,026 bytes) with a Chinese character name, and it succeeded.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what `back pressure` means.

Comment: Back pressure, in brief, is meaning of internal buffer is full and fails to write in writable stream. Then you must stop writing until stream is rewritable.

Comment: OK, thank you. Now I am clear `Backpressure` didn't occur in all my tests. I'll try to recreate it.

Comment: Hm.. I don't why, but I changed the code to not rewrite when back pressure occurs, it worked. I don't know why it happens. I will try this example with different node.js version.